# Coderush and resharper, do they work together?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, resharper, coderush

anyone have any experience of using them together?  How well does it work? or is it just too much grief?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't want to do that.  Both ReSharper and CodeRush want the keyboard.  Specifically, CodeRush remaps the escape key (ESC) for its own purposes.  ReSharper does not like that (note: ReSharper doens't do anything special with the escape key, but it still doesn't like it).

As for choosing between them...they both have their points.  CodeRush has better templating and more refactorings.  ReSharper has built in unit testing for NUnit, and a healthy set of plugings.  ReSharper also has Templates, and a slew of Keyboard short-cuts.

Comment: I vote Resharper. Once you get used to it, you'll never code without it.

Answer (score 19):

I use both tools succesfully. Yes, both wants the keyboard, but they want it in different manner. You can configure them to work together without too much problems. All is about configuration and the learning curve.

Main issues I've faced are: managing parentheses and brackets (just choose which one is going to do this), templates (not a real problem: use tab for one and space for the other), suggestions (configure different keys for each tool).

CodeRush plugins and Resharper plugins works well together and the result is a true delight. There are no conflicts between the tools. Just take two weeks to use it with easy.

Answer (score 9):

I've used Resharper for awhile and recently installed the free Coderush Express too.  After a week or so, I can say that Coderush has not gotten in my way in the slightest, nor has there been contention between the two tools.  Admittedly, I'm way more familiar with Resharper and wouldn't know if half of Coderush was not functioning, but I'm pleased with this set-up currently.

Update: the tab key to go to other usages in CodeRush sometimes interferes when trying to complete a type in a template.  For instance, typing foreach creates a foreach template.  If while editing the template fields, tab is hit, say, to complete the entry, CodeRush zips you to some other place.  Thankfully Esc recovers from this.

See the comments for advice on remapping keys.

Comment: I'm doing this as well.  There are some conflicts, but you can remap the key bindings for coderush using Ctrl+Shift+Alt+O.

Answer (score 5):

I was greedy enough to do that. It took my VS2008 ages to startup. Everything slowed down.  I have 1 Gig of ram. Not sure if that was the case. I removed coderush because I was more used to the resharper keyboard layout.

Comment: 1Gig is a bit small these days I'm afraid.

Comment: yeah I know no one says "Dude, you got 1 gig RAM!!!!" but they say "You just got 1 GIG RAM???psst.."

Comment: I think I would have taken the money you spent on CodeRush and Resharper and bought more memory.  :)

Answer (score 3):

It's not a problem at all to use Resharper with CodeRush. I worked in such style some time. But why? 
IMHO CodeRush in couple with Refactorpro are much better in performance and usability then resharper. Also resharper reduces performance. Almost all features expect probably nunit integration are the same, try to find them in resharper or in codeRush and use only one of them. I prefer coderush

Answer (score 0):

There is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080511/how-to-install-coderush-and-resharper-coderush-shortcut-missing). In one of the answers to that question an article was suggested that seems to be useful:

> Jim Holmes has an awesome blog post that goes through how to make
>   these two products work in the same install.
>
> http://frazzleddad.blogspot.com/2010/01/making-devexpress-resharper-play-nicely.html
>
> I don't even want to think about how many hours and install
>   permutations it took to come up with this sequence.

I did not try it.