# Keyboard Shortcut for Smart Tag in Refactor!

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, add-in, refactoring, coderush

I am trying to get Refactor! for ASP.NET, CodeRush Xpress and Resharper play together.  I installed Resharper, then CodeRush Xpress and then Refactor! for ASP.NET.

I can't seem to get any menu options for Refactor! or CodeRush.  The bracket highlighting is working so I know that it is loading, but the smart tag will not appear (the three dots in a box below selected text).

Is there a keyboard shortcut for that?  Anyone have any ideas why I can't get them to work well together?  I have been able to in the past and I know others have too. (Here are some answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372738/coderush-and-resharper-do-they-work-together) show that.)

Comment: Resharper also does bracket highlighting, so it might be that you're seeing the highlights from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that Refactor! had merged with the smart tags in Visual Studio.

Ctrl+alt+O opens the options for Refactor! and allows you to change it to not merge.

The short cut for the smart tag is Shift+Alt+F10.

This [post](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000506.html) by Jeff Atwood shows how to make this a more reasonable shortcut.

Comment: The Coding Horror blog post moved: http://blog.codinghorror.com/smart-tags-and-sane-keyboard-shortcuts/