# How to install CodeRush and Resharper? CodeRush Shortcut Missing

Tags: resharper, coderush

I am trying to install CodeRush and ReSharper together.

After installing ReSharper, my CodeRush shortcuts disappears.  Does anyone know how to restore my CodeRush shorts with Resharper installed?

This is my current setup:
1. Visual Studio 2008
2. Installed CodeRush XPress 10.1
3. Installed ReSharper 5.1

I am installing on a Windows 7 x64 machine with 8 GB of RAM, so memory will not be an issue.

Answer (score 5):

Jim Holmes has an awesome blog post that goes through how to make these two products work in the same install.

http://frazzleddad.blogspot.com/2010/01/making-devexpress-resharper-play-nicely.html

I don't even want to think about how many hours and install permutations it took to come up with this sequence.

Answer (score 3):

Please try to do the following:

1) Close the IDE.
2) Delete the following folder (back it up, if needed):

%AppData%\CodeRush for VS .NET

This way, the default CodeRush settings will be generated next time you start the IDE.